# Gravity forms, redirect user before submitting the form

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I have a multipage form. And I want to redirect the user to another page if the first question is answered no.

"Are you over 18?"
If No
then send them to another page (outside of the form)
If yes
Then continue to the next question.

I've made a confirmation based on conditional logic. But I have to select "No", click Next and then click Next again for the confirmation to work.
How do I make the confirmation work on the first Next button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

On the end of page break for the first page:

1. Select " Enable Page Conditional Logic"
2. Select "Show" this page "All" of the following match:
3. Set "Are you over 18?" is "Yes"